# Reading from file gives java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720027

Tags: java, android, serialization, objectinputstream

I'm trying to save a LinkedList to a text file that has the ability to append but when I am reading   it I get an exception "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 73720027"

I saw that there are many questions about the same problem but nothing had helped me to solve the issue. What am I doing wrong?

```
  public void saveResult() {
            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "" + File.separator + "prevResultt.txt");

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
            try {
                fileOutputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(context).openFileOutput("prevResultt.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
                } else {
                    objectOutputStream = new AppednableOOS(fileOutputStream);
                }
                objectOutputStream.writeObject(resultsLinkedList);
                objectOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException f) {
                f.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



public LinkedList<Result> loadResult() {
    results = new LinkedList<>();
    File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "" + File.separator + "prevResultt.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            results = (LinkedList) objectInputStream.readObject();
            objectInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return results;
}



import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class AppednableOOS extends ObjectOutputStream {

    public AppednableOOS(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
      reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: There are no [tag:text-files] here. Serialized data is not text: it is binary. It's a bit pointless to test a file for existence *after* you have created it, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

I just toyed around with this for a while, and I might have found a solution. I think your problem is that you are not actually appending to the file. So subsequent writes overwrite the contents of the file and strip the header - thus the exception.

You could try to change this line:

```java
fileOutputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(context).openFileOutput("prevResultt.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To this:

```java
fileOutputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(context).openFileOutput("prevResultt.txt", MODE_PRIVATE | MODE_APPEND);
```

Please let me know if it does not solve your problem. I was able to make it work in plain Java by using an output stream that actually appends instead of overwriting.

Comment: I tried that already and got the same exception. Even without appending at all, i got the same issue. WEIRD

Comment: @RedDot Is there any chance that you can inspect the output file and verify that it does in fact begin with a header? And that it contains only one header?

Comment: @RedDot Another idea: I see that you use `openFileOutput()` for writing the file, but a basic `new FileInputStream()` for reading it. Have you tried using `openFileInput()` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#openFileInput(java.lang.String))?

Comment: The issue is fixed. I just saved an object to the file instead of saving the whole list and when reading I read every object by itself and add it to the list. IT WORKS. Thanks anyway for help bro

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution!